# Referencing an item in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following python code:

```
import regex
original = " the  quick ' brown 1 fox! jumps-over the 'lazy' doG? !  "
s = [i for i in original.split(" ")]
```

I want to write a function called `get_sentence` which takes an element within `s` and returns the sentence as a string to which the element belongs. For example:

```
"brown" ->  "the  quick ' brown 1 fox!"
```

if the first "the" is passed to the function, then:

```
"the" -> the  quick ' brown 1 fox!"
```

if the second the:

```
"the" -> "jumps-over the 'lazy' doG?"
```

What would you pass as an argument to such a function? In C++ I might pass in an std::vector::const_iterator. In C I would pass in an int (array index) or maybe even a pointer.

Comment: I fixed the spelling of `original` in your code.  I hope you don't mind.  Also, the standard python regular expression parser is found in the `re` module, the `regex` module is a little different (just in case you cared ...)

Comment: @Keyser I've seen weirder!

Comment: @mgilson Thanks! I use regex for regex.sub('\P{alpha}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import product, chain
>>> #Assuming your original sentence is
>>> origional = " the  quick ' brown 1 fox! jumps-over the 'lazy' doG? !  "
>>> #Sentence terminators are
>>> sent_term = "[?!.;]"
>>> #I will use regex to split it into sentences
>>> re.split(sent_term, origional.strip())
["the  quick ' brown 1 fox", " jumps-over the 'lazy' doG", ' ', '']
>>> #And then split it as words
>>> #I could have used str.split, but that would include punctuations
>>> #Which you may not be interested
>>> #For each of the words, I create a mapping with the sentence using product
>>> word_map = ((product(re.split("\W",e),[e])) 
                 for e in re.split(sent_term, origional.strip()))
>>> #Chain it as a single list
>>> word_map = chain(*((product(re.split("\W",e),[e])) 
                        for e in re.split(sent_term, origional.strip())))
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> #Create a default dict
>>> words = defaultdict(list)
>>> #And populated all non trivial words
>>> for k, v in word_map:
    if k.strip():
        words[k]+=[v]


>>> words
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'brown': ["the  quick ' brown 1 fox"], 'lazy': [" jumps-over the 'lazy' doG"], 'jumps': [" jumps-over the 'lazy' doG"], 'fox': ["the  quick ' brown 1 fox"], 'doG': [" jumps-over the 'lazy' doG"], '1': ["the  quick ' brown 1 fox"], 'quick': ["the  quick ' brown 1 fox"], 'the': ["the  quick ' brown 1 fox", " jumps-over the 'lazy' doG"], 'over': [" jumps-over the 'lazy' doG"]})
>>> #Now to get the first word
>>> words['the'][0]
"the  quick ' brown 1 fox"
>>> #Now to get the second sentence
>>> words['the'][1]
" jumps-over the 'lazy' doG"
```

Comment: copying entire sentences to memory *each time* you insert a new word to the dictionary, it looks like a memory bomb

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do, but you would probably just pass an integer index. You can't pass a reference to the `the` as the two are both exactly the same.

Comment: After I produce s above, I continue by cleaning it up even further in the form of a new list. So when I work with "doG?", I will actually use "dog" instead in my algorithms - for example when establishing word frequency. However, there are cases where i will need to establish where the "dog" came from. As you pointed out I can use an int.

Answer (score 0):

"Pythonic" way would be to build a dictionary where keys are words, and values are sentences, or a list with sentences that the key belong to.

```
lookup = {}
sentences = split_to_sentences(large_text)
for idx_sentence, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
    for word in split_to_words(sentence):
        if word in sentence:
            s = lookup.setdefault(word, set())
            s.add(idx_sentence)
```

Now `lookup` you have a dictionary where each word has assigned indices of sentences it appears in. BTW, you can rewrite it with some very nice list comprehensions.

Comment: Note that `set()` is the same thing as `set([])` without creating the extra list to just toss away.

Comment: @Jakub M. But the dictionary has no order information. I will not know which element I am referring to with regard to the two "the"'s.

Comment: @Baz: `lookup["the"] == set([0,1])`, "the" is in 1st and 2nd sentence. What more information do you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a dictionary index to a list of sentences:

```
import re
original = " the  quick ' brown 1 fox! jumps-over the 'lazy' doG? !  "

index={}

for sentence in re.findall(r'(\b.*?[.!?])',original):
    for word in re.findall(r'\w+',sentence):
        index.setdefault(word,[]).append(sentence)

print index
```

prints:

```
{'brown': ["the  quick ' brown 1 fox!"], 'lazy': ["jumps-over the 'lazy' doG?"], 'jumps': ["jumps-over the 'lazy' doG?"], 'fox': ["the  quick ' brown 1 fox!"], 'doG': ["jumps-over the 'lazy' doG?"], '1': ["the  quick ' brown 1 fox!"], 'quick': ["the  quick ' brown 1 fox!"], 'the': ["the  quick ' brown 1 fox!", "jumps-over the 'lazy' doG?"], 'over': ["jumps-over the 'lazy' doG?"]}
```

The first 'the' is represented by `index['the'][0]` and the second by `index['the'][1]`